# how can I solve error 207, level 1 invalid column domain

Tags: sql, group-by

I am facing a problem with my query. My group by statement in my table has "domain" I get error :

> error 207, level 16, state 1, invalid column name "domain".

If I do it without domain, then it is no problem.

```
select email, stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email) , '') as domain
FROM [dbo].[Testdatabase]
group by email,domain
```

The idea behind this is to have a domain name of each email.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images. [mcve]

Comment: @yassine can you check my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this one :

```
select email, stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email) , '') as domain

FROM [dbo].[Testdatabase]

group by email,stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email) , '')
```

Comment: i would like also to put the result into another new table, lets call it [Testdatabasenew], how can i do this?

Comment: INSERT INTO Testdatabasenew
select email, stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email) , '') as domain

FROM [dbo].[Testdatabase]

group by email,stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email) , '')

Comment: should i create first the table [Testdatabasenew]?

Comment: select email, stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email) , '') as domain
INTO [dbo].[Testdatabasenew]
FROM [dbo].[Testdatabase]
group by email,stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email) , '')

this query will create

Comment: is my answer incorrect?

Comment: it was totaly correct

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are little bit aware of order of execution in SQL. `SELECT` clause will get executed after `GROUP BY` clause. So, alias would not have applied yet.
Write the query as given below:

```
select email, stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email) , '') as domain
FROM [dbo].[Testdatabase]
group by email, stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email) , '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **@Beso** for your quick help. i also find another solution, it is like this:

select  email, domain
FROM [dbo].[Testdatabase]
cross apply ( select stuff(email, 1, charindex('@', email) , '') as domain) alias
group by email,domain

Comment: Skip the GROUP BY, simply do SELECT DISTINCT: